# CSS div(position relative) ignores another div(position: absolute)

Tags: html, css

Trying to build a site with a fixed, non-scrolling header area (called "top_box") and a scrollable content area (called "middle_box").

The top_box is position: absolute.
The middle_box is position: relative.

The middle_box is "ignoring" the top_box and is displayed across the top_box, instead of being displayed beneath it.

```css
#top_box {
  position: fixed !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  height: 20%;
}
#middle_box {
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="top_box">
  ...
</div>

<div id="middle_box">
  ...
</div>
```

Any ideas why middle_box ignores top_box and starts on the top of the screen instead of starting beneath top_box?

Comment: Set z-index:1 to top_box

Comment: This just flips the display of top_box and middle_box. they are still displayed over each other..

Comment: `absolute` or `fixed` display takes the element out of the flow... so this is expected behavior

Comment: can you explain what is containable scrolling area ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `position: fixed` or `position:absolute` takes the div out of the flow. Because of that your **relative** div won't notice that there is already one above. So it will be placed at the top.

To achieve what you want you have to change your CSS to the following.

I've set the content, in your case the div `#middle_box` to the `height: 1000px` so you can see that the content area is scrollable and your other div `#top_box` stays on top.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#top_box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: #eee;
  z-index: 100;
}
#middle_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="top_box">
  top_box
</div>

<div id="middle_box">
  middle_box
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you have to give `position:relative` to the second box?

```css
#top_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  height: 20%;
  background:red;
}
#middle_box {
  position: absolute;
  top:20%;
  height: 70%;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="top_box">
  TOP
</div>

<div id="middle_box">
  BOTTOM
</div>
```

Comment: You have to give a top: 20% to the second box.

Answer (score 0):

```
#top_box{ 
position: fixed;
top: 2%;
height: 20%;
overflow: hidden;
}

#middle_box
{
position: fixed;
top: 22%; /* this should set to 22%-30% depending at where do you want it*/
height: 70%;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Problem is, i have a picture in the top_box, which is not scaling proportional to the top_box height

Comment: add height attribute to img tag or add CSS to define your image height, if possible post code with your image

Answer (score 0):

`fixed !important;` would prevail over `absolute`

also *beneath* it wouldn't be, since it will start *within* the parent, not below it

```css
#top_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  height: 20%;
  
  background-color: yellow;
}

#middle_box {
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  overflow: auto;

  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="top_box">
Lorem Ipsum 1
</div>

<div id="middle_box">
Lorem Ipsum 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what actually u mean about scrollable content area . I think you mean it's a scrolling section when there is overflow content. If that scrollable content meants that you want a overflow scrolling. You can make this without using position.  I change the middle box % to px so that scroll when overflowing content. Any Question ask me in comment thanks.

```css
#top_box {
  text-align: center;
  height: 20%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#middle_box {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 280px; /*change the height otherwise 70% will never scroll that content*/
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
padding:0 10px;
}

h1.tittle {
  text-align: center;
}

#footer_box {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="top_box">

  <h1>
Non-scroll Top Header area
</h1>

</div>

<div id="middle_box">
  <h1 class="tittle">
Scrolling Header 
</h1> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
  has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
  publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
  took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
  sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
  standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
  leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
  versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
  type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
  recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
  the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
  Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum
  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
  not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
  like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
  type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
  Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
  text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised
  in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
  industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
  typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem
  Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
  not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
  like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
  type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
  Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<div id="footer_box">

  <h1>Footer area</h1>

</div>
```